# Fresh ubuntu installation - memory usage went from 3% to 41% - should I be concerned and how to remedy?

Tags: memory, memory-usage

My memory usage was a 4% after a fresh ubuntu 12.10 installation

[image]

after i install php packages etc using this gist, https://gist.github.com/4372049

my memory usage now reached 41%.

[image]

should i be concerned?

if not, then at what memory usage level should i be concerned?

if yes, then what remedies should I do?

UPDATE:

based on suggestion to post my top followed by >

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Run `top` to get an overview of all processes running on your system.
Then, inside `top`, press `>`. There you have it, the processes on your system ordered by memory. Now you can see what is causing this memory usage spike. Post the top 5 processes in the list.</strike>
OK, it looks like php and mysql are the offenders. Do you want these running in the background...?

Comment: I do want them running. So I guess I have no choice but to accept it. Thank you!